# wordpress blog url is appended with post-postid automatically how to remove it?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, blogger, permalinks

- In my blog I had observed that all my blog URLs old & new are automatically appended with post-postid which had great impact on SEO & traffic of my site
- Raise in 404 pages increased due to this issue
- I had tried checking all plugins for any impact on the blog but I was not success

Any one help me out :

For all my wordpress blog urls (**https://www.example.com/XYZ/**) it is appending post-postid like this **https://www.example.com/XYZ/post-12345** which I want to avoid.

Please help me how to remove post-post id appended to blog URL.

Thanks!

Comment: and your permalink settings hasn't been changed?

Comment: I didn't change any permalink settings. It remains same